# Upload iOS app in AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, application-loader

This is my first uploading to AppStore.

I create zip file with project folder in icon folder. Then in Application Loader i choose "Deliver Your App" and choose there my zip file. But Application loader give this error:
[image]

What should i do? Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I archived folder with projects, but i should archived some file from .app

Comment: have you read [part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2)? :)

Answer (score 3):

oh if only it were that simple....

Have a read of this [guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)

Should start you off in the right direction.